# Ordering items in index

Tags: memoir, indexing

An unexpected (to me!) index ordering in memoir. Here's a MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

Aristotle \index{Aristotle}
(CP)      \index{:@(CP)}
$\to$     \index{0@$\to$}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Since `:` comes in ascii  between`0` and `A`  I would expect the index to be ordered

```
->, 1

(CP), 1

Aristotle, 1
```

But I get the unwanted

```
(CP), 1

->, 1

Aristotle, 1
```

Query: how to force what I want -- index listing symbols first (gap) list of rules of inference (gap) main alphabetic sequence.

Comment: MakeIndex sorts symbols before numbers, then alphabetic strings.

Comment: That doesn't give me quite what I want, as I need to use the "sortkey@" trick to get two blocks of entries into a bespoke order, before the main alphabetic ordering. I was wondering why sortkeys `nnn` came AFTER sortkeys `:nnn` when I'd expect the other way about given the ascii codes ...

Comment: `:123` starts with a symbol.

Comment: Ooops, sorry, I see what you mean! (Mmmmm, this is annoying .... !)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an extract from a very good manual on MakeIndex ([`texdoc ind`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/support/makeindex/ind.pdf))

[image]

What this doesn't say explicitly is that the sorting is

1. Symbols
2. Numbers
3. Strings

This explains your problem: `\index{:@(CP)}` will be sorted *before* `\index{0@$\to$}`, because the former entry is classified as a symbol. However, you can make a symbol for the latter entry by using `\index{:0@$\to$}`.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

Aristotle\index{Aristotle}
(CP)\index{::@(CP)}
$\to$\index{:0@$\to$}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]